# Scifi dystopian like audio book in which a ship crashes into Earth and becomes Godlike

Tags: story-identification, audio-book

I'm trying to identify an audio book I heard many years ago but can't recall the name. The story involves a human settlement on the moon and a  science spaceship with biologic tech and nano tech on board.

The ship AI becomes sentient, and then at some point crashes into Earth. The surviving astronaut wakes up centuries later. The ship evolves into some sort of God-like entity flowing out the crater in which it crashed, using its biotech to play with and mutate the creatures around it. The protagonist meets his ex wife, or a clone of her, who is now in a human spider form. He later learns that the all that remains of the human race is the moon colony.

Comment: The books about a sentient ship with god-like powers are the Pandora sequence by Frank Herbert, but the ship wasn't crashed and it didn't take place on Earth.

Comment: I fund it..the book is called " the  omega project"

Comment: @BrunoAndersLopezSchardelman For people in future who may be looking for the same thing, you should post your find as an answer then mark it as the correct answer.  I'll give you a few hours before I poach your answer. ;)

Comment: @Vanguard3000 Except there are multiple books called The Omega Project, and none of the plot synopsis I read on Goodreads are an exact match so far as I can see

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Since OP answered his own question, I assume he knows which one. Also, the first hit is for Steve Alten's novel by this name. And looking at synopses for this book leads me to believe it is the correct one.

Comment: @Vanguard3000 Yes the OP knows but hasn't given us the author.  Also the Steve Alan one talks about a "habitat submerged beneath the Antarctic Ice Sheet" instead of a space ship.  So that is why neither you nor I have actually posted an answer :-)

Comment: @Dijkgraaf No that's not why; I had honestly forgotten about it. From several reviews on Goodreads it seems to have a lot of similarities. In any case, I guess we'll have to agree to disagree on this one. The main thing is OP found the book they were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Per the OP comments above, this is most likely "[The Omega Project](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1611659)" (2013) by Steve Alten.